# Lookup table index for struct array

Tags: c

I'm reading a binary file where one of the bytes defines a type of data.

Typically:

```
0x13 => FOO
0x14 => BAR
```

But, as it is, there can be multiple definitions of same type, then real type is
defined elsewhere, **but it is not always accessible**. Therefore I would like to 
print all possibilities if no sub specification is defined.

E.g.:

```
0x13 => FOO
0x14 => BAR
0x14 => BAZ <-- also "type" 0x14
0x15 => XEN
```

To store the type definitions and descriptions I have a struct in the format of:

```
struct data_def {
    char id;
    char *name;
    char *desc;
    ...
};
```

---

If it was possible I would have had an array as in:

```
static const struct data_def data_db[][] = {

    ...
    } /* index 0x13 */
        {0x13, "FOO", "This is foo", ...}
    }, /* index 0x14 */
        {0x14, "BAR", "This is bar", ...},
        {0x14, "BAZ", "This is baz", ...}
    }, /* index 0x15 */
        {0x15, "XEN", "This is xen", ...}
    }
}
```

In order so that `data_db[0x14][1].name == BAZ`, etc.

But AFAIK this is not possible. Or is it? (C89).

---

I am looking for another way to do it. Was thinking of something like this:

```
static const struct data_def data_db[] = {
    ...
    {0x13, "FOO", "This is foo", ...},
    {0x14, "BAR", "This is bar", ...},
    {0x14, "BAZ", "This is baz", ...},
    {0x15, "XEN", "This is xen", ...}
}
```

And then have a lookup table as in where each first entry starts. This could
off course also be dynamically created by looping `data_db`, but would rather
have it statically defined (I think – I haven't decided):

```
static const char data_index[] {
    ...
    0x20, /* at index 0x13 of data_index */
    0x21, /* at index 0x14 of data_index */
    0x23, /* at index 0x15 of data_index */
}
```

Giving that one could print, (or other),  by doing e.g.:

```
while (data_db[data_index[0x14 + i]].id == 0x14) {
         print data_db[data_index[0x14 + i]].name
         ++i
}
```

---

Is there a better way to solve this? I imagine this is something that has been done
a billion times before with similar scenarios. I would rather not use any libraries
outside of the standard library as this eventually is only a small part of the program
and the rest of the code is *"free"* of that as well.

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally flawed.  You cannot do this without more information.  You're trying to use something which is *not* unique as a unique identifier.  Given only a number you cannot determine if it means `foo` or `bar` or `whatever`.  You need a different approach.

Comment: Believe you are missing the point. As I wrote I want to list all types of same identifier. If 0x14 has two types, I want to list those two. So I would have an unique identifier for that **group** – which I get by index array. Further the data input is from external source and for historical reasons the type/id is overlapping.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I think I did.  However, it's obvious that, if one value can map to N values, you need a value => collection mapping.  That means that, at the most basic level, you need an array of arrays, where an index maps to N structure instances.  Your best bet would be an associative container, none of which exist in the C standard library. Of course, this *is* a problem that has been solved, many times, and many third party solutions exist

Comment: @Zimzalabim Do you have a known limit on the number of clashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a shot in the dark, but **if** the number of types within an identifier group has an upper bound and **if** you can utilize a value that you know will not be one of your types, you could do something like this:

```
#define MAX_NUM_TYPES    3
#define INVALID_TYPE     0xff

struct Data_Def{
    unsigned char id;
    char * name;
    char * desc;
};

static const struct Data_Def data_db[][MAX_NUM_TYPES] = {
 .
 .
 .

    {    /* Index 0x13  */
         /*  id           name      desc            */
        {    0x13,        "FOO",    "This is foo"    },
        {    0x13,        "BAR",    "This is bar"    },
        {    INVALID_TYPE, NULL,    NULL             },
    },
    {    /* Index 0x14  */
         /*  id           name      desc            */
        {    0x14,        "BAZ",    "This is baz"    },
        {    INVALID_TYPE, NULL,    NULL             },
        {    INVALID_TYPE, NULL,    NULL             },
    },
};
```

And if you want to print...

```
unsigned char index = 0;
/* Print all types within a group with id 0x13. */
while ((data_db[0x13][index].id != INVALID_TYPE) && (index < MAX_NUM_TYPES))
{
    printf("%s", data_db[0x13][index].name);
    index++;
}
```

This may not work at all for what you're trying to accomplish and depending on the number of types per group, it may be a complete waste of code space.  However, it is one way of attacking the problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just use a function pointer which determines if the type is valid? or am I missing something... Then have a lookup of true values... smaller and faster...

Comment: @Jay Do you have an example you could post?

Comment: +1. But; it is 256 ID's where approximately 50 has duplicates ranging from 2 to 6. That would mean `256 * 6` and thus a bit big for my liking. (Not that you could know from the information I gave in Q). – I'm considering using a more complex index array, but the whole project has been in freeze mode as of late due to other prioritized projects.